# Make dynamic dictionary from json file

Tags: c#, json, linq, dictionary

I have json file like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield_10008": {
              "value": "c1"
        },
        "customfield_10009": {
              "value": "c2"
       }
            ...
    }
}
```

and I would like to create dictionary in c# like:

```
key:    value
"customfield_10008":"c1"
"customfield_10009":"c2"
```

How I can achive this? I load json in this way,

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("data.json");
```

and don't know how to create dict like above

Answer (score 2):

A little bit linq tricks can help you

```
var dict = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("data.json"))["fields"]
           .Cast<JProperty>()
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (string)x.Value["value"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Come through the values and collect them:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var field in obj.fields)
{
    result.Add(field.Name, Convert.ToString(field.Value.value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have json which do not have type in compile time, you can use `dynamic` type at that time.

I would parse above json using `dynamic` type and generate `dictionary` with parsed value :

```
var dicValues = new Dictionary<string,string>(); // this dictionary contains key value pair result
dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText("data.json");
dynamic availableFields = res["fields"];
if (availableFields != null)
{
    foreach (var field in availableFields)
        dicValues.Add(field.Name, field.Value["value"].Value);
}
```